# How to create column names with subscript in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with air pollutant concentrations. I want to draw boxplots for each of the pollutants, but don't know how to present the name, like "PM_{2.5}" in Latex code, with the subscript "2.5". I know the "expression" function can make it work in labels but not variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not going to copy-paste the code here, but I think that what you want is on Github. Please check [here](https://gist.github.com/benmarwick/5cfeda1d20ff9ab3231a5de8fac36213).